# One click shutdown Ubuntu and load into alternative bootup

Tags: windows, grub2, dual-boot, shutdown

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 11.04 and Windows 7.

My GRUB bootloader defaults to Ubuntu.
I mainly use Ubuntu, but I occasionally need to bootup Windows to do a few things.

If I need to do something in Windows I can "shutdown" Ubuntu and select Windows 7 in the bootloader. However, it would be more efficient if I could do this in one click from Ubuntu.

- Is it possible to press a key in Ubuntu which means "Shut down, and then boot into Windows"? (or for that matter Shut down and boot into any non-default bootup)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In case you know the entry number for your Windows installation (start counting with `0` for first position) in the grub menu you can reboot into Windows (assuming to be 3rd on the list) by this command:

```
grub-reboot 2
```

Alternatively you can also use the textual entry used:

```
grub-reboot '<type entry here>'
```

This command can also be put in a launcher for "single-click" usage.

To make this procedure work we need the entry `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` in `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: Thanks. After reading your answer, I did a few searches and found the following post useful to flesh out a few more details about grub-reboot : http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/how-to-reboot-in-windows-from-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 6):

@Takkat has answered the question, but I thought I'd describe a few more details in case it might help others.

- Boot menus count from zero. I have five elements in my boot menu. The fifth element is Windows, thus, to reboot to Windows, I had to issue the command `grub-reboot 4` (i.e., not 5). **UPDATE:** *see comments below about this possibly changing*.
- In order to edit `/etc/default/grub` I issued `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`.
- To make the procedure work, I had to modify the existing value of `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` and then run `sudo update-grub`.

I then created a script based on the [webupd8 example](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/how-to-reboot-in-windows-from-ubuntu.html):

I called it `winboot` and put in in `~/bin`

```
#!/bin/bash
gksu grub-reboot 4
gksu reboot
```

Comment: Ty for giving us further details. Mind that after the next kernel update you will likely have to change your position number.

Comment: @Takkat - Would there be a way of auto selecting the lowest line number (I'm assuming Windows is listed last in Grub2) to avoid that problem? @Jeromy - Thanks for posting this up.

Comment: I've not tested this but by using the textual description for Winodws you should be on the safe side.