# Select on which partition reboot

Tags: boot, command-line, scripts

Is there any way to select a partition for the next boot.

For example:

```
sudo reboot boot=/dev/sda2
```

I would like to make a system backup script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[grub-reboot](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/grub-reboot.8.html)

We can force to reboot to a different boot entry in our Grub menu by using grub-reboot:

```
grub-reboot ENTRY
```

Replace `ENTRY` with the number or the menu item title of your Grub boot menu.

Note that this will only work however when we allow Grub to store the last saved entry by editing `/etc/default/grub` and adding (or uncommenting) the following line (reboot to take effect):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

Also see: [One click shutdown Ubuntu and load into alternative bootup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42390/one-click-shutdown-ubuntu-and-load-into-alternative-bootup).