# Can you tell the system which boot partition to boot into before you reboot in Ubuntu-Win Dual Boot?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04

I have a dual boot system Windows 7 64-bit and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit freshly installed today and running. GRUB 2 is in charge of partition selection upon booting but I was wondering if there is a way to tell ubuntu which partition to boot into upon performing a reboot rather than having to wait for GRUB to load.

Comment: yes you need to alter the grub config and then do a grub update. BUT this will take far longer then selecting the option during a reboot :P

Comment: there's grub-reboot: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42390/one-click-shutdown-ubuntu-and-load-into-alternative-bootup

Comment: Ah very well thank you both @Takkat, it doesn't sound too bad I will give it a go.