# Ubuntu power option to reboot directly into other OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I'm running two different Ubuntu-based distributions on my system (Zorin OS 16.1 and Ubuntu Studio 21.10 with the kernel from the upcoming 22.04 LTS) and I would like to know if I can create a power menu button to reboot directly into Ubuntu Studio without having to interrupt the bootloader and select it from the grub menu. Maybe if there's a way to reboot to the grub boot menu without a power cycle, that could work if there's no way to pass which one-time option to the grub with a command.

Comment: No you can not do that Sorry.

Comment: Ubuntu Studio is a Ubuntu system (*not Ubuntu based*); it's an official [*flavor*](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) using only packages found in Ubuntu repositories so is on-topic here, however Zorin OS is not (*it's based on Ubuntu system*)    You can create a *shutdown* icon/script that will cause the other OS to boot next time (*I did it, but I'd not want to do it again.. it wasn't worth it*) but that would require change to both OSes inc. Zorin which is off-topic here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One click shutdown Ubuntu and load into alternative bootup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42390/one-click-shutdown-ubuntu-and-load-into-alternative-bootup) The answers may need some adaptations (for example, replacing `gksu` with `sudo`) but it may fit with your needs.